# Magnified fonts messed up after reboot

Tags: fonts

I have the following problem with the built in magnifier option (Settings->Display->magnification slider) of Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS Trusty. In the beginning my problem occured every few days but since a couple of days after every reboot: Directly after logging in all system fonts and menus are messed up like on the following pictures.

http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150324/r6r48ghh.png

http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150324/8h5gne7q.png

Changing the magnifier factor to another value fixes the problem until the next reboot. Any ideas to solve it permanently?

Which logs should I provide? The syslog doesn't show anything interesting (as far as I can estimate).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: As a workaround until this is fixed: Does anybody know how to change the magnification via command line? I'm thinking on a startup script that switches the value after every login.

Comment: I just updated to kernel 3.19. Unfortunately no improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since updating to kernel 4.0, the issue hasn't appeared again. I guess it is fixed in the new version.